# Problem with loading data into SharePoint via SSIS

Tags: sharepoint, ssis

I'm trying to load some data from SQL Server into SharePoint via SSIS. All services are on-premise.
My package's scheme looks like this:
[image]
As you can see here, the error appears on the last step when I try to load new data into SharePoint. Inside conditional split step I check if there is a SharePoint list ID in Merged dataset: if no - insert.

We have a lot of packages like this one, but this time I've met some problem I don't know what to do with:

```
Error: 0x0 at Orders from NX STORE, LOAD ECM Giveaway: Error on row ID="1": 0x80020005 - Unspecified Error - Check SharePoint Server Logs if possible. 
Error: 0xC0047062 at Orders from NX STORE, LOAD ECM Giveaway [154]: Microsoft.Samples.SqlServer.SSIS.SharePointListAdapters.PipelineProcessException: Errors detected in this component - see SSIS Errors
   at Microsoft.Samples.SqlServer.SSIS.SharePointListAdapters.SharePointListDestination.ProcessInput(Int32 inputID, PipelineBuffer buffer)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ManagedComponentHost.HostProcessInput(IDTSManagedComponentWrapper100 wrapper, Int32 inputID, IDTSBuffer100 pDTSBuffer, IntPtr bufferWirePacket)
Error: 0xC0047022 at Orders from NX STORE, SSIS.Pipeline: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "LOAD ECM Giveaway" (154) failed with error code 0x80131500 while processing input "Component Input" (164). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
```

I've tried to google this error code, but my problem definitely not about data types. I admit that there is no row with ID="1" inside my SharePoint list (it was deleted earlier), but I'm not shure that the problem is related to this.

Any help or even idea would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you check the Sharepoint Server logs ?

Comment: @AmiraBedhiafi, I don't have any access to SharePoint logs, because I'm not responsible of it in my company, and my colleague who's responsible isn't qualified enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case this type of error appeared because of columns with a **Lookup** type inside that SharePoint list.

Usually records inside such columns look like "1;#sample" and to load data you should place an **id** part of such records ("1") instead of **value** part ("sample").
When I understood this I tried and it worked great for me!

[This discussion](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c6136a77-583d-469e-b0bc-f4438fb33c8a/is-there-a-way-to-insert-data-into-a-lookup-column-type-on-a-sharepoint-list-destination-in-ssis?forum=sqlintegrationservices) helped me to resolve my problem. Check it for extra details.